# Как правильно реализовать jwt-аутентификацию?

Tags: аутентификация, jwt

Пытаюсь разобраться с jwt-аутентификацией. Начитался статей и у меня возник вопрос. В большинстве туториулов, которые мне попадались, использовали отдельный обработчик запросов для "refresh_token". Что-то типа такого:

```
serverApp.post("/refresh-tokens", ...)
```

В таком случае получается, что когда время жизни "access_token" иссякнет, то сначала сервер вернет клиенту соответственную ошибку, после чего клиент должен обратиться к "/refresh-tokens", получить новые токены и вновь повторить запрос. Есть еще вариант. [Здесь](https://gist.github.com/zmts/802dc9c3510d79fd40f9dc38a12bccfc) автор предлагает следующее:

1. Клиент(фронтенд) проверяет перед запросом не истекло ли время жизни
   access token'на
2. Если истекло клиент делает запрос на POST auth/refresh-tokens {
   fingerprint: string } в body и соответственно refreshToken куку.
3. Сервер получает запись рефреш-сессии по UUID'у рефреш токена
4. Сохраняет текущую рефреш-сессию в переменную и удаляет ее из таблицы
5. Проверяет текущую рефреш-сессию:
   5.1. Не истекло ли время жизни 
   5.2. На соответствие старого fingerprint'a полученного из текущей
   рефреш-сессии с новым полученным из тела запроса
6. В случае негативного результата бросает ошибку
   TOKEN_EXPIRED/INVALID_REFRESH_SESSION
7. В случае успеха создает новую рефреш-сессию и записывает ее в БД
   Создает access token
8. Отправляет клиенту access и refresh token uuid (взятый из выше
   созданной рефреш-сессии).

Внимание стоит обратить на первый пункт. То есть, чтобы не делать заведомо "неудачный" запрос, который вернет ошибку из-за иссякнувшего времени жизни "access_token", стоит на клиенте проверить нужно ли нам будет генерировать новую пару токенов.

Мой вопрос заключается в следующем. Зачем нам нужен отдельный запрос на "/refresh-tokens"? Почему, скажем, сразу же на первом запросе к серверу не сгенерировать пару токенов, если "access_token" не валиден по времени? Зачем нужна двойная работа? Даже если "/refresh-tokens" будет в виде отдельного сервиса, то зачем нам возвращаться к клиенту и от него делать запрос, если можно сделать это с сервера? Я в этих вопросах новичок, потому могу чего-то не понимать. Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться. Спасибо.

Comment: Представляю себя на их месте:
1) "/refresh-tokens" будет в виде отдельного сервиса -- это хорошая причина
2) "...если можно сделать это с сервера..." -- Для этого надо научить все сервера ходить и получать токены, а так надо только клиента.
А по времени почти то же выйдет.

Comment: @Sergei  А почему все сервера? Ну... В своем примере я скорее говорил о монолите, но в любом случае, зачем учить каждый сервер, если можно научить этому сервис авторизации?

Comment: @Sergei Да и что касается времени... Разве одинаково? То ли пойти на сервер, получить отказ(вернуться), вновь пойти на сервер ща токенами, и опять стучаться к приватным обработчикам, или же пойти на сервер, не пройти валидацию, но тут же пойти за токенами(можно даже не перенаправлять а вызвать соответствующую функцию), после чего сразу же отдать запрос тому, кто идёт дальше. Таким образом мы лишний раз не возвращаемся и это наверное как должно быть быстрее. Или я чего-то все ещё не понимаю?

Comment: 0) можно сделать и так, как вы говорите; я излагаю не свое мнение, а обосновываю мнение автора
1) Если раз в несколько минут что-то такое происходит, пользователь не заметит; он время не сэкономит; поэтому 2) если сервер сходит на сервер, на это тоже нужно время 3) Автор возможно хочет разделить ответственность: обычный сервис может или отработатрь, или отказаться, он не должен уметь ходить за токенами, это не его дело; код сервисов становиттся проще

Comment: @Sergei понял Вас, спасибо